# Add a row in a table and parse json file jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a beginner and i have the following question. I have a table and i want to add the following row using jquery.

```
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>
<select name="my_type">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="1">One</option>
<option value="3" selected>Three</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
```

But I want to parse  a json(setup.json) file that i have locally in order to have when the page loads the value equal to one for example.

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $.getJSON('setup.json',function(data){
...
});
```

The json is simple as {"my-type":1}
Thank you!

Comment: You want to parse the JSON and add a row based on that?

Comment: are both the page and the json file being loaded locally? Otherwise you will get a cross domain error

Comment: yes they are loaded locally

Comment: You're going to have to explain what you want a little better. Go step by step, because what you're asking now doesn't seem to quite come all together.

Comment: So the first step is that i want to add a row in a table. The row inside has a dropdown select. If the user has selected "One" from the dropdown and saved i create a json{"my-type":1} locally. Then i want to retrieve the value from the json when he refreshes the page and show him what he has selected. You can think it as a simple user interface. I haven't the option to use php to do it. I use only cgi and javascript.